# Reduce an array based on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, reduce

My task is to reduce an array of objects based on up to three following conditions:

1. Return an object from the array based on the user language, for example, `ru_RU`.
2. If no user language was provided, return the object based on the application default language, `en_EN`.
3. If no user language provided, and the array does not have an object which corresponds with a default application language, return the first object in the array.

Here is an example of the array:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "language":{
      "id":1,
      "isoCode":"en_GB"
    }
  },
  {
    "id":2,
    "language":{
      "id":2,
      "isoCode":"es_ES"
    }
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "language":{
      "id":3,
      "isoCode":"ru_RU"
    }
  },
  {
    "id":4,
    "language":{
      "id":4,
      "isoCode":"fr_FR"
    }
  }
]
```

Here is a solution that works:

```
const [userLanguageMessage] = data.filter(
    (message) => message.language.isoCode === USER_LANGUAGE,
);
const [defaultLanguageMessage] = data?.filter(
    (message) => message.language.isoCode === DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
);
const [firstLanguageMessage] = data;
const message = userLanguageMessage || defaultLanguageMessage || firstLanguageMessage;
```

I would like to make it more *neat*, so to speak, and wonder if I could use reduce to achive it.

Comment: One way to clean this up immediately is to set `const selectedLanguage` to either `USER_LANGUAGE` or `DEFAULT_LANGUAGE`. Then you only need a single `filter()` call.

Answer (score 1):

With this given structure, something like this should work

```
result = 
    data.find(x => x.language.isoCode === userLanguage) ||
    data.find(x => x.language.isoCode === 'en_US') ||
    data[0]
```

or in a more efficient way:

```
function get(data, lang) {
    let def = null;
 
    for (let x of data) {
        if (x.language.isoCode === lang)
            return x;
        if (x.language.isoCode === 'en_US')
            def = x;
    }
    
    return def || data[0]
}
```

but you should be really using a lookup `Map` for this.

As a side note I always wondered what's so special about `reduce` that people feel somehow obliged to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with **reduce** in O(N):

```
const reduceArray = (arr, userLanguage, defaultLanguage) => 
  arr.reduce((res, item) => !res || 
    (userLanguage && item.language.isoCode === userLanguage) ||
    (!userLanguage && defaultLanguage && item.language.isoCode === defaultLanguage) ? 
    item : res, null);
```

**UPD**: Well, there is a problem to break reduce loop without mutating the input array, so my solution is not perfect: the iteration will continue when the user language item is found... so I suggest the @georg solution is better.

Comment: Try `reduceArray(data, 'xxx', 'fr_FR')` ;)

Comment: 'xxx' is not a valid language code, but you're right it will not work that way